# Get all string fields in a model rails 4 throws ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR in circleci

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

In my rails application, I have tried to get all the string fields using columns and pass the fields to a transform method to escape the values.

```
class Coat < ActiveRecord::Base
  transform (Coat.columns.select { |c| c.type == :string }.map(&:name).map(&:to_sym)
end
```

When I deployed this feature branch in circleci pipeline it will execute *rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=TEST* to create the tables and columns through migrations. But the method that I've used executed before creating the table.

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
required simplecov
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "coats" does not exist
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"coats"'::regclass
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"coats"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:592:in `async_exec'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:592:in `block in exec_no_cache'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:473:in `block in log'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:467:in `log'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:592:in `exec_no_cache'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:584:in `execute_and_clear'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:160:in `exec_query'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:733:in `column_definitions'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:186:in `columns'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:43:in `columns'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/attributes.rb:93:in `columns'
/src/app/models/coat.rb:6:in `<class:Coat>'
/src/app/models/coat.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Is there any way to get the column names after creating the table or any other method to get the string fields of a table?

Comment: Where did you put this line of code? What are you trying to achieve? You have clearly identified why the error occurs but we are unclear as to what you would like to do from here.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit what are you trying to do with this and why?
Is something being used during migrations? When saving records to the DB?